# How to get app path in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I want to get application path in my application, but I haven't found any way. If anyone knows how can I get application path in my app, It would be great.

Many thanks,

Comment: is 'app path' a filesystem path for current instance or url path?

Comment: No, I need file system path. for example 'c:\apps\'

Comment: btw, how do you want to use this path?

Comment: Actually I need it for IO file.

Comment: Do you understand that it's a temp directory usually? it's removed on each restart, and contains only what you put into original WAR (so you can read w/o knowing filesystem path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get absolute path for application, you can get like this.

```
String applicationPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")
```

It will provide absolute path for application.

Comment: In Grails 3.0.6, this is not working anymore. Result is NULL.

Comment: Indeed. What is the solution for Grails 3.X ?

Answer (score 1):

`I think , most of the time was difficult to find the path inside gsp.` 
but , you can **use this** :

```
var path = "${resource()}"+"/mycontroller/myaction" ;
```

**gives you the path of the application.**

`Inside controller like when you need to upload file :`

```
def webRootDir = servletContext.getRealPath("/")
def userDir = new File(webRootDir, "/payload/${session.user.login}")
userDir.mkdirs()
uploadedFile.transferTo( new File( userDir, uploadedFile.originalFilename))
```

Answer (score 0):

copy this in your controller

```
print webRequest.baseUrl
```